# Regex redirect rule for missing part of the path

Tags: redirect, regex

i want to have a redirect rule for:
before: /ratgeber/one/two/three/, after: /one/two/three/
or
before: /ratgeber/one/two/three/four, after: /one/two/three/four/

So i just only want to redirect to the same path except for the first part /ratgeber/. Do you know what a regex redirect rule could do this?